# How do I lock down a windows programs with Usernames and passwords?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a program that uses a view to display information. Usernames and other valuable information.

How do I set it so that at the first run of the program brings it to a different form to input a new password?  The user has never logged in before.  Then the second run of the program prompt for that password.

Ideally the solution will be done in C# and using Winforms.

However an algorithm is acceptable.

---

The program has been aborted. Please close this thread

Comment: Are you DISPLAYING passwords, usernames and other valuable information, or are you trying to make a login page?

Comment: In a well-designed password-handling system, it is impossible to ever display stored passwords, because you store cryptographically secure irreversible hashes instead.

Comment: Salt and one-way hash any stored passwords. Use unique salts for each password hash to protect against rainbow attacks.

Comment: You need to explain exactly **what** your app needs to do, Mohit.

Comment: No. And I just want to display the data. What control should I use. I am using a database to store my data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

look at forms authentication in c#. lots a controlsbuilt in to .net to help you.

Comment: Forms authentication is an ASP.NET rather than a C# technology. You cannot use it in a WinForms app (without much fuss and tinkering!).